# How to find red points (in square borders)

Tags: python, math

How to find this points if we know only radius and a?

[image: square with circle]

i just know how to find the points in circle borders. but how to do this with square. I have attached code example. And get errors in square_borders. Dont know how to fix it

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

map = np.zeros((500,500), dtype=np.int8)
cv2.circle(map,(250,250), 250, 50,2)
position = (250,250)
r = map.shape[0] / 2

ray_numbers = 120
field_of_view = math.radians(360)
step_angle = field_of_view / ray_numbers
start_angle = math.radians(0)

def circle_borders(start_angle,step_angle):
    for _ in range(ray_numbers):
        target_x = round(position[1]- r * math.sin(start_angle))
        target_y = round(position[0] - r * math.cos(start_angle))
        cv2.line(map, position, (target_x,target_y), 100, 2)
        start_angle += step_angle
        
def square_borders(start_angle,step_angle):
    for _ in range(ray_numbers):
        target_x = round(position[1] + r * math.tan(start_angle))   # here is the 
        target_y = round(position[0] + r)                           # trouble
        cv2.line(map, position, (target_x,target_y), 255, 2)
        start_angle += step_angle



circle_borders(start_angle,step_angle)
square_borders(start_angle,step_angle)

cv2.imshow('circle and square borders', map)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the red points are not in the circle borders, but in the square

Comment: Is it a math solution you're looking for? Because you don't show any code, and at what point you are stuck in the code.

Comment: Yes. And I would like to know how to find them correctly with a given angle

Comment: What else do we know about the red points? Some are either not points, or overlapping and inside the square border. This is too vague to answer.

Comment: What given angle?

Comment: What angle are you talking about? Are this points by any chance projections of certain angles into a square? If so you should make this clear in the question. A simple tangent will give you this values, since you will have a triangle rectangle with a known angle and one side being the radius.

Comment: for example. I want to draw line from point E to square border. 

I know how to make it for circle border:
x_border_circle = e - r * sin(angle)
y_border_circle = e - r * cos(angle)

Now need to do the same things but with square borders.

Comment: You should definitely update your drawing. For a red point at the right you can make a triangle where the base (horizontal line) is r and you just need to know the height (vertical line). A tangent is defined by y/x. So your y value will just be `r*tan(angle)`. So the coordinates of that point will be `(E+r, E+r*tan(angle))`.

Comment: This is basic trigonometry. And without code problems, this is really not the place to ask and answer this question.

Comment: To generate a correct answer I think you should provide a little more information about the task you carry out, in addition you are not including code or software development content, I would recommend you check [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126719/whats-the-probability-that-three-points-determine-an-acute-triangle/129756#129756) and pose your question in one better way and with more information.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I have attached the example. Can you point out my mistakes?

Comment: you have to be careful, since tangent won't work for all angles. there are certain angles for which the tangent is infinite. you need to consider some side cases. also the projection in each side of the square might need some signs to be tuned. You will need to check those cases separately.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a math question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
def square_borders(start_angle,step_angle):
    for _ in range(ray_numbers):
        b = max(abs(math.sin(start_angle)), abs(math.cos(start_angle)))
        target_x = round(position[1] - r * math.sin(start_angle) / b)
        target_y = round(position[0] - r * math.cos(start_angle) / b)
        cv2.line(map, position, (target_x,target_y), 255, 2)
        start_angle += step_angle
```